# Change application settings from codedUI test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there anyway to change the application/user settings in the application under test in a codedUI test? If so how?

particularly for user settings it would be useful to be able to control the environment of the test regardless of any changes I have made locally to settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot access any variables in the application under test directly. Only if the are controls they are accessed under coded ui test with accessbility option. One way you could modify the settings is to have them set in the config/xml file and have the coded ui test case method to modify the xml file. This assumes that the application uses the user settings in the xml file dynamically. If not it should not be too hard to change it so, if you can extract the settings to an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

For settings that aren't bound to controls, you could simply replace references to each setting with an if statement that tests if the application is under test.

Alternatively, you could create a partial class or extension that shadows the relevant settings value properties and returns the values you want when under test.

Naturally, you would have to have a variable visible to your entire application that defines if a test is running, and have your test class set it.

Comment: This just begs the question how would I set a variable in the application under test in a codedUI test. If I can set a variable in my application from my test class then I can set the setting directly.